# RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX upgrade - The name 'ExpandMode' does not exist in the current context

Tags: .net-3.5, telerik, asp.net-3.5, upgrade, rad-controls

**Distinct error:**

The name 'ExpandMode' does not exist in the current context

**Code:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (!this.IsPostBack && !this.sectionTree.IsCallBack)
     {
        //populate the first level of tree nodes
        foreach (SiteSection section in SiteSectionCollection.GetRootSections())
        {
           RadTreeNode node = new RadTreeNode(section.Name, section.AssetId.ToString());
           node.ExpandMode = ExpandMode.ServerSideCallBack;
           this.sectionTree.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
     }
  }
```

**Background:**

When upgrading from "RadControls for ASP.NET" to "RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX", I ran into several issues.  The web.config file was converted by the Upgrade Wizard.  I started with 233 .NET compilation errors (28 distinct errors) which I quickly resolved, but I still have 36 errors (13 distinct issues) left from drastic API changes that I still haven't resolved.  I will post these 13 errors as questions on stack overflow to save me some time.  While I'm waiting I will try downloading their control demos and understand how the controls work for their newest release and answer them myself for those others haven't answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that the RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX are different from the RadControls for ASP.NET. The later (non-AJAX controls) are quite old at this time, and lack a lot of the functionality that the new controls (ASP.NET AJAX) will contain. This can cause some API calls to be different, as you have seen above, but taking a look over the [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx) or [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction.html) to look at the functionality you currently have implemented is a good step for figuring out how to implement them in this new product.

As for the issue at hand here, you should just be able to use the **TreeNodeExpandMode** property which is part of the RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX, as opposed to the ExpandMode which is a part of the RadControls for ASP.NET. For more information about the various expand modes you can look into [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/programming/loadondemandmodes/defaultcs.aspx).